# How to prevent x11vnc attacks: attempts to unauthorized logins?

Tags: security, vnc, fail2ban

My computer was freezing for 1 second every 5 seconds.
I found it was someone repeatedly trying to log in through x11vnc.

Is there some way I can have it reject connections from an IP address for a half hour after 3 failed login attempts? or something like that?

edit:

It looks like this is something fail2ban can do. But fail2ban doesn't come with a configuration for x11vnc, so a good answer would be how to configure it.

This is what a login failure looks like in `journalctl -u x11vnc` :

`Jan 30 14:41:58 computername x11vnc[1686]: 30/01/2020 14:41:58 authProcessClientMessage: authentication failed from 176.113.115.244`

Comment: Why not just block the IP address range the attacks originate from?

Comment: I think something that I can set once and not worry about it any more is better than something where I have to react every time a new attack comes from a new IP range.

Comment: This is something that [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) should be able to handle I think - regardless, I'd suggest tunneling any x11vnc traffic over SSH and using the `-localhost` option to prevent ANY direct connections to ports 59xx

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to solve this problem. **Here is my solution**.

## Stop all connections to `x11vnc` except `localhost`

The easiest way to do this is to start `x11vnc` with the `-localhost` option. If you setup `x11vnc` to startup at boot as a systemd service you have have a file `/lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service` where you may have a line like:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -rfbport 5900 -shared -localhost
```

Note, the last option is `-localhost`. This option means `x11vnc` will only listen to the localhost IP address, which is 127.0.0.1. This special IP address always refers to the computer itself. This means only the computer where `x11vnc` is installed can access `x11vnc`. Other computers will need to access `x11vnc` indirectly using `ssh tunnel`.

## Setup `openssh-server`

You will need the `openssh-server` running in the same computer running `x11vnc`. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter the command:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

This will install the ssh server. See [configuring the ssh server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring) instructions for security related information. I recommend you enable key based login and disable password based login for `ssh`.

## Setup `ufw` and `fail2ban`

`ufw` is installed in Ubuntu but may not be enabled. Enter the following two commands in the terminal:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

to enable `ufw` and allow `ssh` connection from other computers. If you already have `ufw` enabled and have setup rules to allow `x11vnc` connections, you may want to delete those rules.

Similarly install and configure `fail2ban`. Follow one of the [tutorials](https://linuxhandbook.com/fail2ban-basic/) on how to configure `fail2ban` for `ssh`.

## If you are behind a router...

and have setup port forwarding for the port 5900 (or something similar) now is the time to change that. You want to change that rule to port 22 so that connection requests for `ssh` are forwarded instead of connection requests for `x11vnc`.

Note, ports 5900 and 22 are the default ports for the respective services `vnc` and `ssh`, if you have changed the default, you will need to make corresponding adjustments.

## How to remote connect to `x11vnc` now?

We are done with setting up the computer running `x11vnc`. Now we need to make some changes to the computer that you use to remotely connect to this computer.

#### Note: all the changes and commands below this line is for the client computer used to connect to the `x11vnc. I will call this computer the laptop.

### Use `ssh` tunnel using command line:

Use the following command at the terminal

```
ssh user@host -L 5900:localhost:5900
```

where `user` is the username in the computer running `x11vnc` and host is the hostname or IP address of that computer. This command must continue to run as long as you want to keep remotely connected to the host computer. Don't close the terminal while this is running.

If you haven't setup your `x11vnc` server to start at boot, you can setup the `ssh tunnel` and using the same command start the `x11vnc` server in the remote computer. If you want to do that, use the command:

```
ssh user@host -L 5900:localhost:5900 x11vnc -localhost
```

While one of these commands are running in the terminal of the laptop, run the app you use to connect to the remote computer as usual.

If you use `Remmina` to connect to the x11vnc server ignore this command line section and read on.

### Setup Remmina

If you use an Ubuntu laptop to remotely connect to `x11vnc` then you probably use the app called `Remmina`. This app has the capability to do the `ssh tunnel` built-in, so you don't have to open a terminal and type the command.

Edit the setting of the VNC connection you have setup in Remmina for your remote connection and go to the <kbd>SSH Tunnel</kbd> tab as shown below:

[image]

Make sure the following are enabled/checked:

- Enable SSH Tunnel
- Tunnel via loopback address
- Same server at port 22

as shown in the picture above. Save the new Remmina setting and try to connect. If all went well only you should be able to connect to your `x11vnc` server and no one else will.

## Connect from Android

OP asked for instructions for connecting to the remote computer running `x11vnc` from an Android phone/tablet in the comments.

### Install and setup `bVNC` in the Android device

`bVNC` is available in the Google Play store.

When you open `bVNC` for rhe first time, you will see some permission requirements. Review them and decide if you want to accept them or not. Then you will see a page of feature lists. Press the <kbd>Close</kbd> button at the bottom right of the page to get to the settings page.

Change the connection type from **Basic VNC** > **Secure VNC over SSH** and you will see the following screen:

[image]

Fill up the settings as follows:

- Connection type: **Secure VNC over SSH** (as noted above)
- Title: Give it a meaningful name indicating which computer the connection is for.

#### SSH Tunnel Settings

- SSH Server: This is the IP address or host domain name for the `x11VNC` computer. This is the server address you would have entered for basic VNC setup.
- 22: The default `ssh` port is pre-filled as 22. Change it only if you have changed the `openssh-server` default settings in the computer running `x11VNC`.
- SSH Username: This is the user name you use to login to the computer running `x11VNC` when you sit in front of it.
- SSH Password: This is the password you use to login to the computer running `x11VNC` when you sit in front of it.
- SSH Passphrase: This is needed only if you have setup a passphrase when you generated the private-public key pair. The private-public key pair can be used instead of the SSH Password above.
- Use Key: This tells `bVNC` to use the private-public key pair instead of the user password.
- Manage Key: This button will take you to another page where you can generate the the private-public key pair and share the public key so that it can be added to the set of "Authorized Keys" in the computer running `x11VNC`. This is needed only if you check the box to **Use Key**.
- Configure AutoX: Disabled. Leave as is.

#### VNC Connection Settings

- Localhost: Leave as is.
- 5900: Leave as is unless you have changed the default VNC port in the computer running `x11VNC`.
- VNC Username (optional): Add the user name if you have setup an user name within `x11VNC` configuration.
- VNC Password: add the VNC password here if you have setup it up within `x11VNC` configuration.
- Keep: Check this box to save the VNC password in `bVNC`.

After setting up `bVNC` you should be able to connect to your remote computer running `x11VNC` from the Android device.

## Setup Private-Public Key Pair in `bVNC`

If you have setup your `ssh-server` in the computer running `x11VNC` to use only key based logins, then you won't be able to use passwords under **SSH Passwords** above. In that case you will need to check the box **Use Key** and use the **Manage Key** button above to generate and somehow get the public key to the correct folder and file in the computer running `x11VNC`.

Press the **Manage Key** button to see the following window:

[image]

First, you need to generate a new private-public key pair. Press the **Generate New Key** button, and keep Type to **RSA**. The default Bits size of 2048 should be okay.

You will be asked to move your finger on the Android screen for a while to generate entropy for the random number generator and the keys will be generated.

You will need to get the public key to your computer running `x11VNC` in one of the three ways listed as the three buttons:

- Share Public Key
- Copy to Clipboard
- Save Public Key to File

The first may be the easiest. Click the Share Public Key button and select Gmail (or whatever email you use) and send it to yourself.

You may also specify a file name such as `rsa.pub` and click send it to file button, and send that file as attachment to yourself.

To import the public key into the computer you will have to physically (locally) login to that computer.

Check if you already have the folder `/home/$USER/.ssh` in your Home folder and if so, if you already have a file called `/home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys`. In a terminal use the command:

```
ls ~/.ssh
```

If you see contents of the folder including `authorized_keys` then you have them.

If you already have the file `authorized_keys` you will need to add the contents of the public key into that file. Open that file in a text editor and the saved `rsa.pub` sent via email from your phone in another editor window and copy the contents from one to the other appending at the end of `authorized_keys`.

If you don't have the `authorized_keys` file, and the `.shh` folder, then use the following commands to create them:

```
mkdir -p /home/$USER/.ssh && touch /home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then copy and the paste of the contents of `rsa.pub` into the `authorized_keys` using a text editor of your choice.

If you have just created these folder and file, you will need to change the permissions of the folder and file so that only you can read them. Use the following command to change the permissions. Note: the `ssh` server won't read the file if the folder and file do not have the strict permission. This is a safety measure.

```
chmod 700 /home/$USER/.ssh && chmod 600 /home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Note: You can replace `$USER` with your login name in the computer running `x11VNC`.

Test if you can login from `bVNC` using the key without using **SSH Password**.

Once you are sure that key based authentication is working, disable password based `ssh` login following the ansers to this question: [Disable password authentication in ssh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435615/disable-password-authentication-in-ssh)

Hope this helps

Comment: For this solution, you would also need to include instructions for connecting to the VNC server from an Android client.

Comment: @beauxq I have added an Android VNC client setup section. Let me know if you have problems.

Comment: @beauxq consider accepting the answer as correct.