# Access to my local server from laptop

Tags: server, ssh, gpu

I have a local GPU machine at home and want to be able to connect remotely to it with the laptop. What are the best practices and solutions for this?

Local GPU machine: Ubuntu 20

Laptop: Mac os

Update:

- I want to do programming (e.g. vs code) and run my code on the local server.
- It's fine to have terminal-based access (e.g. ssh). But I also need to synchronize my code between local machine and laptop while I'm coding with vs code (code is located on local machine).
- Please provide detailed steps of setuping ssh connection, automated synchronization of the code (or data) and run script on the local machine.

Thank you.

Comment: What is a GPU machine? What version of Ubuntu are you using? What OS is on the laptop? You need way more info here f you want any help.

Comment: The standard solution is to install OpenSSH server on the Ubuntu system, and use a SSH client on the Mac to make a connection. Does that answer your question?

Comment: How do you want to connect remotely, ie. what service do you want to use, because there are different ones? You can use a text-only shell using SSH, as in the above comments, or if you want to use graphical desktop, something like VNC or RDP server would be needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remote desktop access between 2 Ubuntu 20.04 devices over the internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267872/remote-desktop-access-between-2-ubuntu-20-04-devices-over-the-internet)

Answer (score 0):

The two main technologies to look into are "ssh" and "vnc".

If all you need is away of logging in remotely to open a text terminal (to run build scripts in, etc), then ssh is your tool of choice.

If you need to be able to "see the screen" of that remove machine (in a window), then the tool(s) to look into are VNC (TigerVNC etc); these allow you to show that remote machine's desktop in a window on your mac. Warning: it's not always trivial to set up.