# Possible to use x11vnc with encryption?

Tags: encryption, remote-desktop, vnc, ssl

I'm trying to setup VNC with SSL (or other encryption) for remote access.

(I don't need VNC in particular; that just seems like the the most common way of doing this. I'm open to other solutions.)

I installed x11vnc:

```
sudo apt install x11vnc -y
x11vnc -storepasswd
x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat  -rfbport 5900 -shared -usepw
```

Run that way it works well, but my VNC client (on Windows; I tried both VNC Connect and tightvnc) complains that the connection is not encrypted. I need a secure connection.

But if I add `-ssl` to the x11vnc command line, I can't connect at all and the client says it can't connect with "your chosen security setting".

I've Googled a lot and am stuck.

FWIW I also:

- Tried installing Chrome Remote Desktop by running `chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb` downloaded from Google. I get "Error: Cannon satisfy dependencies":

[image: Error: Cannon satisfy dependencies]

- Installed xrdp; can't get past a completely blank screen with that.

I'm on Kubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent x11vnc attacks: attempts to unauthorized logins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206883/how-to-prevent-x11vnc-attacks-attempts-to-unauthorized-logins)

Comment: No - that doesn't seem even related. Are you a chatbot?

Comment: Have you read the answer to the linked question? In VNC over ssh tunnel, the encryption is provided by ssh.